# AngularJS search array without filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

Is there a way to search an array without utilising a filter or custom filter in AngularJS?

A filter is the obvious choice but for some coursework I am doing it is not permitted and searching for answers is proving useless.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean search an array? can you extend your request?

Comment: You could have two arrays. One with the result and one with the items to search. You could loop through the array and then anything that matches populate the result array. Seems a bit stupid not to use a filter

Comment: The answer to the asked question is 'Yes'.  But I think you're really asking for options, which brings up lots of questions: Is the array sorted?  Is it required to use Angular methods?  What are you trying to find? what are the elements of the array?